# How to filter grep results?

Tags: bash, grep, awk

I am new at writing scripts. So I am hoping this is simple.
The script I am writing is used to gather system information and save it as an html file.

When I run:

```
sudo lshw -short
```

it list all of the hardware on a system.

When I run:

```
sudo lshw -short | grep processor
```

it returns (the dots represent spaces)

```
/0/4                        ...........................................processor................................................   AMD FX(tm)-6100 Six-Core Processor"
```

My question is how to I remove everything in front of processor.
Or how do I only display what is after "processor". 
I tried several other options for grep and tried to find an awk command to work, but I have failed in my attempts.

If more information is need let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In versions of `grep` that support the PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) extension, you can do

```
sudo lshw -short | grep -Po 'processor\K.*'
```

The `-o` says to only print the matching text, and `\K` modifier causes anything to its left in the matching text to be excluded from the result.

If you want to also remove any white space following the literal text `processor`, you can do

```
sudo lshw -short | grep -Po 'processor\s*\K.*'
```